# How to extract value from Path parameters in play2 mini?

Tags: scala, playframework, play2-mini

The method I will use is DELETE request, and I have this url for web service call:

```
http://www.localhost:9000/example/com/foo/bar
```

I want to extract /foo and /bar and store it in a variable.

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

I'm using play2-mini for web service and dispatch for scala for making http request.

Comment: Are you using play2-mini with java or scala ?

Answer (score 2):

Play has a very sophisticated way of passing parameters and that is through Routes definition. In your conf/Routes file define a Route like

```
GET  /example/com/:foo  controllers.yourcontroller.deleteAction(foo: String)
```

when you will enter

```
http://www.localhost:9000/example/com/user
```

in your browser, `deleteAction` defined by your Controller will be invoked and string "user" will be passed to it in its parameter `foo`. there you can manipulate it.
Note that part of URI followed by colon is dynamic. It will accept anything that fulfills requirement of being a string and will forward it to deleteAction by storing it in `foo` variable.

Comment: oops! I didn't notice the tag. just saw [play] in body. To be honest i didn't know there is something like play mini. sorry, but I am not eligible for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp as shown in the following code :

```
object App extends Application { 
  def route = Routes(
    Through("/people/(.*)".r) {groups: List[String] =>
      Action{ 
        val id :: Nil = groups
        Ok(<h1>It works with regex!, id: {id}</h1>).as("text/html") 
      }
    }, 
    {
      case GET(Path("/coco")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request =>
        println(request.body)
        println(play.api.Play.current)
        val result = QueryString(qs,"foo").getOrElse("noh")
        Ok(<h1>It works!, query String {result}</h1>).as("text/html") }

      case GET(Path("/cocoa")) => Action{ request =>
        Ok(<h1>It works with extractors!</h1>).as("text/html") }
      },
    Through("/flowers/id/") {groups: List[String] =>
      Action{ 
        val id :: Nil = groups
        Ok(<h1>It works with simple startsWith! -  id: {id}</h1>).as("text/html") 
      }
    }
  )
}
```